# Opening a Web page then filling in part of the form on that page

Tags: c#, .net

I need to open a Web Page and then fill in part of the form on that page with the data i got from my user (like name and phone number) then let them fill in the rest of the form, without using selenium !!?

Is this possible at all and if so, how could i achieve this in C# !!?

Comment: where do you want to open it?

Comment: I hope [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/89abc30c-32c9-420a-8f39-a2d3f8425a78/fill-text-boxes-from-a-web-pages-using-a-windows-c-app?forum=csharpgeneral) will solve your issue :)

Comment: @DanielA.White in the user's browser

Comment: @zackraiyan i know i could post but i need to open the browser for the user, when he clicks on a button and fill in the data i got from him, then he could fill in the rest of the form himself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Whatever design you are using, the solution is the same. Wherever you have the data to fill the form, make sure to pass it through the web page you are opening. Then, one in many options is using javascript to fill the form with the data.

Using c#, I suggest you check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: will you be more specific please because i have worked with mvc, web api's and ... but i can't find what i am looking for